# Border for Dynamically created buttons in Windows Application C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

Hai all,
I am dynamically creating button at runtime in a c#.net Windows Application, I want to draw a border for the dynamically created button how can i do it, i tried this

```
 private void DrawBorder(Button bt)
        {
            Graphics g = bt.CreateGraphics();
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, bt.DisplayRectangle, Color.FromArgb(229, 227, 227), ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
            g.Dispose();
        }
```

but it is not showing any error but i can't see any border

Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a button that draws differently, you should probably create a new class inheriting from `Button`, and in it you would override `OnPaint` and/or `OnPaintBackground` and implement your drawing logics, such as drawing a border.

The reason your current solution is not working probably depends on *when* you are calling your `DrawBorder` method. If your drawing code is not executed as part of handling an `OnPaint` event, then the graphics you draw will be drawn-over in the next paint.

But anyway, instead of drawing the border yourself, can't you set the `Border` proerpty on the `Button` object?

Comment: I guess you can't set the color of the standard border of a button in Windows Forms.

Comment: @Uwe Keim: that may be the reason. Though (229,227,227) looks very close to the "standard" control color... :)

Comment: no can set flatapperanceproperty for border if flatstyle is flat